# Yii2 Gridview row by row css expression

Tags: gridview, yii2

What is the correct way to do a row by row css expression. In Yii 1 is was rowCssClass. I couldn't figure out how to achieve this with Yii2. I had tried this, but wasn't sure I was on the right lines:

```
        'rowOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $grid){
        if($data->option->correct_answer == 1){

            return ['class' => 'danger'];
        }
    },
```

I'm unsure where to get the parameters for the function from when dealing with the dataProvider though.

Comment: btw this is an excellent example how a framework can block your work. Doing this manually would take 5 seconds, trying to find out how to do this (in a horribly complicated way with Yii) took me 2 hours. Just saying :(

Comment: @Sliq Could be clearer I would agree. I remember I did make the initial error though. Hopefully this answer/question will save people time though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use $model instead $data.

In my variant:

```
   'rowOptions' => function ($model, $index, $widget, $grid){
      return ['style'=>'color:'.$model->status->color.'; background-color:'.$model->status->background_color.';'];
    },
```

In your case:

```
   'rowOptions' => function ($model, $index, $widget, $grid){

      if($model->option->correct_answer == 1){
        return ['class' => 'danger'];
      }else{
        return [];
      }
    },
```

Comment: @useruser1852788 I seem to get array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array.

Comment: looks like you should return array, so I've edit the answer - added else part of "if" statement with empty array as return value.

Comment: Same thing, stack is this `foreach ($this->columns as $i => $column) {
            if (is_string($column)) {
                $column = $this->createDataColumn($column);
            } else {
                $column = Yii::createObject(array_merge([
                    'class' => $this->dataColumnClass ? : DataColumn::className(),
                    'grid' => $this,
                ], $column));
            }`

Comment: I thought we talk about rows... and class for rows. Your code from last comment is about columns. Show whole code of your widget call.

Comment: User1852788 it is about rows. The code is the stack error.

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake, putting the rowOptions inside columns array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

add class name for your row

```
'rowOptions' => ['class'=>'rowData'],
```

then manipulate it through css

```
<?php

$css = <<< CSS
//example
.rowData:hover{

}
CSS;
$this->registerCss($css);
?>
```