# How to change background of 1 row in Yii2 Gridview

Tags: css, gridview, row, yii2

I'm working with Yii 2, and it's grid view to show information.

Now, my problem is that whenever a user scans two identical serial numbers and/or mac addresses, it should highlight the row (change color to red), and show some error sign or whatever.

**Screenshot:**
[image: Current Grid View]

What I want it to look like:

[image: Desired Grid Highlighting]

I'm new to Yii2 and don't exactly know how they do it with the grid view. I've been researching on this specific problem but couldn't find anything.

Code for Gridview

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'scan-batch-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'product_ID',
            'value' => 'product.name'
        ],
        'SN',
        'MAC',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                    return Url::to(['scan-batch/view',  'id' => $key, 'scan' => $model->scan_batch_ID]);
            },
            'buttons' => [
                'update' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return '';
                },
                'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return '';
                },
            ],
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

**EDIT**

I only want to know how to change the color of only one row.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Got it!

[Yii2 : Adding Classes to Rows in the GridView (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtWadQOBklQ/)

[Yii2 Gridview row by row css expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372531/yii2-gridview-row-by-row-css-expression)

Simply add rowOptions to your gridview.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'scan-batch-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'rowOptions'=>function($model){
            if($a == $b){
                return ['class' => 'danger'];
            }
    },
```

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for posting your answer Paramone. Worked great.

Here is my implementation:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'rowOptions' => function ($model) {
        if ($model->name == 'test') {
            return ['class' => 'info'];
        }
    },
```

Comment: Not a problem at all, glad it helped you out! ;)